# How to visualize this kind of information

Tags: machine-learning

I am training a logistic regression algorithm and it returns me the following information for each iteration. I am collecting these entities as arrays for the entire classification.

Can you suggest me some ways to visualize it? For example, is it appropriate to plot loss vs accuracy? Or what kind of graphic type I should use?

```
***** Iteration #74 *****
Loss: 170.07
Feature L2-norm: 12.5714
Learning rate (eta): 0.00778819
Total number of feature updates: 236800
Loss variance: 5.01839
Seconds required for this iteration: 0.01
Accuracy: 0.9800 (784/800)
Micro P, R, F1: 0.9771 (384/393), 0.9821 (384/391), 0.9796

***** Iteration #75 *****
Loss: 166.81
Feature L2-norm: 12.4385
Learning rate (eta): 0.00769234
Total number of feature updates: 240000
Loss variance: 4.68113
Seconds required for this iteration: 0.01
Accuracy: 0.9800 (784/800)
Micro P, R, F1: 0.9771 (384/393), 0.9821 (384/391), 0.9796
```

Answer (score 0):

1. For your own analysis you should plot accuracy vs. time, so you know when you start to overfit.
2. For publication, you can pick the metrics others have reported, so you can compare to them.

Answer (score 0):

I' dont think taht you should visualize this information. All what you could see is that L2 norm is decreased over time(since it is target minimsation function) and accuracy increased. But since F1 is so high I think it is metrics for evaluation on training data. 
So I would recommend to do Micro P, R, F1: 0.9771 (384/393), 0.9821 (384/391), 0.9796 such report on test data(data wich is not used for training) and create plot of iteration vs F1. And then you will see when you actually start overfitting data by peak on the plot.